# Compile time error while adding unicode \u0022

Tags: java, string, unicode, cxf, soap-client

I'm trying to add double quotes in a string using the unicode, but when I do so i get the compilation time error.

```
String unicCode = "\u0022"; //This line gives a compile time error.
```

The compilation error is that I get is

> String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote.

Could some one help me to understand what are the escape characters required to be used to append a unicode of a double quotation mark (").

Comment: What do you want your string to contain? The single character `"`?

Comment: Why dont you define it as char instead?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm basically trying to preapre a String to be used to call a web service. my requirement is to add _"abc"_ (including the double quotes) as a part of my soap request. I have tried it by '\"abc\"' but when the request is sent it is converted to '&quot;abc&quot;'

Comment: @almasshaikh : I tried including it as char, but again (as mentioned above) the char is converted to &quot;. Basically, when i add unicode other that \u0022 the character is passed accurately. Thus trying the unicode way.

Comment: @user3701861 i edited the answer, is this what u looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String quote = "\u005c\u0022";
        System.out.println(quote);
    }
```

**Output**

```
"
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String quote = "\u005c\u0022" + "abc" + "\u005c\u0022";
        System.out.println(quote);
    }
```

**Output**

```
"abc"
```

If you wanted to put the two double quote chars into the string literal, you can do it with normal escape sequences. But you can't do with `Unicode escapes` because Java provides no special treatment for Unicode escapes within string literals.

```
String quote = "\"";
```

// We can't represent the same string with a single Unicode escape.

// `\u0022` has exactly the same meaning to the compiler as ".

// The string below turns into `"""`: an empty string followed

// by an unterminated string, which yields a compilation error.

```
String quote = "\u0022";
```

Comment: I tried the solution, but i still get &quot; when the Soap request is called.

Comment: @user3701861 try using UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Yeah, java compiler converts the escaping sequence to UTF before a code parsing that sometimes leads to the errors.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6

Answer (score 3):

The `\uXXXX` escaping is already early resolved when the javac compiler reads the java source text. It has nothing to do with only string literals and backslash escaping there. And `\u0022` is the same as char `"`. *And hence needs escaping in a string literal: `"\\u0022"` which is read as `"\""`.* This means was designed to enable a pure ASCII representation of a java source using any unicode. But you may escape ASCII too:

```
public \u0063lass Test {
    public static void \u006dain(String[] args) {
```