# How to encode unicode characters like \u0022 and \u005c (\ and ") in a Java string?

Tags: java, unicode

I am working on a Java based Android app which uses a custom web font to show different icons. To use the icons I have created a simple `HashMap`:

```
Map<Integer, String> iconMaß = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("help", "\ue004");
        put("info", "\ue005");
        ...
        put("search", "\u0022");
        put("delete", "\u005c");
    }
};
```

This works fine, except that using `"\u005c"` and `"\u0022"` is not possible. `"\u0022"` represents `"` and `"\u005c"` is `\`. It seems that compiler translates the escaped unicode character and `"\"` is no valid string of course. However, using `"\\u005c" does not work either, since now the first backslash escaped the second one and instead of having one unicode character I now get the string` \u005c` (sixs chars long)...

So, how to escape the unicode chars correctly?

Of course I could solve this specific problem by using `\` and `"` instead. However, I would like to be sure that the problem does not show up with other chars as well and I would like to know how to properly escape the unicode chars.

BTW: Using `"\u005c"` and `"\u0022"` in Kotlin is no problem and delivers the correct result.

Comment: A helpful post on Java and Unicode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533097/java-unicode-encoding

Comment: Double-quote and backslash are the only characters that behave specially in String literals.  So their Unicode equivalents `\u022` and `\005c` are the only Unicode escapes that will also behave specially.   So, problem solved, I think (;-D)

Comment: If you can format like this, the backslash (and other unicode chars) should print right:
`int test = 0x005c;`
`System.out.println((char)test);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\u` in java is not a string escape. It's an escape that is picked up *directly by the parser itself*. This is valid java:

```
String x = \u0022Hello\u0022;
```

The reasoning is fairly simple: Sometimes, you edit source files in e.g. US-ASCII, or ISO-8859-1, but you still want to put, say, a unicode snowman in your source file, which would then be impossible.

To put a backslash in a java string, `"\\"` is all you need. For a quote, `"\""` is all you need. If you insist on always using the number for some bizarre reason, octal escapes are available but do not exceed 255 (so you can just cover ASCII-and-a-bit with these). Otherwise, construct them. Easy enough. Thus, either:

```
put("delete", "\"");
```

or

```
put("delete", "" + (char) 0x5C);
```

Kotlin made a different decision and more or less posits that you edit your source files in UTF-8, period. Java made the decision that it's a bridge too far to just decree this. Possibly related to the fact that java's origins are about 25 years earlier than kotlin's. Back then UTF-8 was a pretty cool idea, instead of a de facto standard.

Answer (score 2):

This seem like pervious [explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968213/compile-time-error-while-adding-unicode-u0022)

Also this adding this way also worked

```
 Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<String, String>()
        {
            {
                put("help", "\ue004");
                put("info", "\ue005");
                put("search", "\u005c\u0022");
                put("delete", "\u005c\u005c");
            };
        };

        testMap.entrySet().forEach(
                entry -> {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + entry.getValue());
                }
        );
```